# How to select landlocked countries in Africa using Select By Location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select, select-by-location

I wish to select the landlocked countries in Africa using just Select by Location.

I have already dissolved the boarders to get one big polygon and I thought I might combine these two telling ArcGIS somehow that I just want the countries to be selected that are not touching the outside borders, but how can I do the next step?

Answer (score 3):

If landlocked means "not connected to the sea", you can first select all countries that intersect the continent formed by dissolving all the countries (new selection , intersect) then you remove those that touch the seas (i.e the boundaries of the continent). (remove from selection, share a line segment).

Comment: Great, worked perfectly. Thx :)